# Scala - Future.sequence on Tuples

Tags: scala, future

I have a Seq of Tuples:

```
val seqTuple: Seq[(String, Future[String])] = Seq(("A", Future("X")), ("B", Future("Y")))
```

and I want to get:

```
val futureSeqTuple: Future[Seq[(String, String)]] = Future(Seq(("A", "X"), ("B", "Y")))
```

I know I can do:

```
val futureSeq: Future[Seq[String]] = Future.sequence(seqTuple.map(_._2))
```

but I am losing the first String in the Tuple.

What is the best way to get a `Future[Seq[(String, String)]]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the futures in tuples to map each tuple to future of tuple first,
then sequence:

```
Future.sequence(
  seqTuple.map{case (s1, fut_s2) => fut_s2.map{s2 => (s1, s2)} }
)
```

Step by step, from inner terms to outer terms:

1. The inner `map` converts `Future("X")` to `Future(("A", "X"))`.
2. The outer `map` converts each `("A", Future("X"))` into an `Future(("A", "X"))`, thus giving you a `Seq[Future[(String, String)]]`.
3. Now you can use `sequence` on that to obtain `Future[Seq[(String, String)]]`

Answer (score 5):

The answer given here works fine, but I think `Future.traverse` would work more succinctly here:

```
Future.traverse(seqTuple) {
  case (s1, s2Future) => s2Future.map{ s2 => (s1, s2) }
}
```

This function [involves](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#traverse%5BA,B,M%5BX%5D%3C:IterableOnce%5BX%5D%5D(in:M%5BA%5D)(fn:A=%3Escala.concurrent.Future%5BB%5D)(implicitbf:scala.collection.BuildFrom%5BM%5BA%5D,B,M%5BB%5D%5D,implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future%5BM%5BB%5D%5D) converting the input argument :)